# UITableView stops scrolling

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, scroll

My TableView, which uses custom cells, sometimes 'stops' scrolling when I return from a DetailView.

I can push the view up a couple inches or so, and the lower cells do come into view, but the scrollview should be 4 or 5 windows in height.

The detail view is called through a segue.  In addition to the back button, I also trigger a return with a swipe gesture.  Either way it happens. - not all the time though.

Hope this is enough info.  Does anyone have any ideas what I am screwing up?
Thanks!

Here's some code:

```
- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
int row = [indexPath row];
int sect = [indexPath section];
NSDictionary *shift = [globals.shifts objectAtIndex:sect];
NSLog(@"\nShift = %@", shift);
NSLog(@"\nEmployees = %@", [shift objectForKey:@"Employees"]);
NSArray *employees = [shift objectForKey:@"Employees"];
NSDictionary *employee = [employees objectAtIndex:row];

globals.badge = [employee objectForKey:@"Badge"];
globals.name = [employee objectForKey:@"Name"];

return indexPath;
}

- (void)receivedData:(NSData *)responseData {
NSError* error;
globals.report = [NSJSONSerialization
          JSONObjectWithData:responseData
          options:kNilOptions
          error:&error];

globals.shifts = [globals.report objectForKey:@"shifts"];
[globals.ai removeFromSuperview];
[table reloadData];
self.title = [ [NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@ - %@",
              [globals.clientNames objectAtIndex:globals.curClient],
              [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate: globals.weekEnd]];
self.title = [ [NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",
              [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate: globals.weekEnd]];
}

-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

if( globals == nil || globals.report == nil )
{
    appDelegate = (MSIAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    globals = [appDelegate globals];
    [[self view] addSubview:globals.ai];
    NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:
                          @"http://www.msiwebtrax.com/Client/%@/WeeklyReport?id=%@&start=%@&end=%@", [globals.clientIDs objectAtIndex:globals.curClient], globals.userName, [globals.formatter stringFromDate: globals.weekEnd], [globals.formatter stringFromDate: [globals.weekEnd dateByAddingTimeInterval:(-7) * 24 * 60 * 60] ]];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: urlString];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0 ), ^{
        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:
                        url];
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(receivedData:)
                               withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
    });
}
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

UIScrollView *tempScrollView=(UIScrollView *)self.view;
NSLog(@"scroll view dimensions: %f, %f", tempScrollView.contentSize.height, tempScrollView.contentSize.width);

self.dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[self.dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
[self.dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];


// Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

// Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
// self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

Here's the number of sections/rows

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
int sections = [globals.shifts count];
return sections;
}

- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
NSDictionary* shift = [globals.shifts objectAtIndex:section];
int rowCount = [[shift objectForKey:@"Employees"] count];
return rowCount;
}
```

--

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"EmployeeHoursCell";
EmployeeHoursCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if( cell == nil ) {
    cell = [[EmployeeHoursCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

NSUInteger section = [indexPath section];
NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
globals.employees = [[globals.shifts objectAtIndex:section] objectForKey:@"Employees"];

cell.Row.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%3d", (row+1)];
cell.Id.text = [[globals.employees objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"Badge"];

cell.Name.text = [[globals.employees objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:@"Name"];

NSArray *days = [[globals.employees objectAtIndex:0]  objectForKey:@"Days"];

cell.Hrs1.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[[days objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"Rounded"] ];
cell.Hrs1.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f", [cell.Hrs1.text doubleValue]];

cell.Hrs2.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[[days objectAtIndex:1] objectForKey:@"Rounded"] ];
cell.Hrs2.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f", [cell.Hrs2.text doubleValue]];

cell.Hrs3.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[[days objectAtIndex:2] objectForKey:@"Rounded"] ];
cell.Hrs3.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f", [cell.Hrs3.text doubleValue]];

cell.Hrs4.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[[days objectAtIndex:3] objectForKey:@"Rounded"] ];
cell.Hrs4.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f", [cell.Hrs4.text doubleValue]];

cell.Hrs5.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[[days objectAtIndex:4] objectForKey:@"Rounded"] ];
cell.Hrs5.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f", [cell.Hrs5.text doubleValue]];

cell.Hrs6.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[[days objectAtIndex:5] objectForKey:@"Rounded"] ];
cell.Hrs6.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f", [cell.Hrs6.text doubleValue]];

cell.Hrs7.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",[[days objectAtIndex:6] objectForKey:@"Rounded"] ];
cell.Hrs7.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.2f", [cell.Hrs7.text doubleValue]];

return cell;
}
```

Okay all - in the viewWillAppear method, I tried reloading the table, which didn't have any impact.  But I then reset the contentSize to 0,0 before and it seems to work fine now, not entirely sure why - but I noticed the first time I come back from a detailview, the height is set to around 2000, the second time I return it is zero - at which point it works.  So I set it to zero and reload.
Thanks Darren and all for the responses!

Comment: Imagine you were your grandma (yes, she does iOS coding). Now read your question again and tell us if you really got the point. Wouldnt it be a lot more helpful if you supplied some of your code to her? Wouldnt if be a lot more helpful if you supplied a screenshot of your app to her?

Comment: It sounds like your table view's contentSize is getting reset incorrectly. Since you're using custom cells, maybe it has something to do with your tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: method. But yeah, you will really have to post your code for the table view controller, data source and delegate.

Comment: check the most obvious possibility. you say it happens "sometimes". perhaps the tableview is correctly allowing you to scroll to all of the data. Add some logging and look at what is being returned by `numberOfSectionsInTableView:` and `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`.